# sitecore 8 - getting "Failed" JS dialog when clicking on treeview links

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When I tried to click on the treeview links from "Insert Options" (and in other windows as well). 
Please check this below link for the error screen shot.

[Error on tree-view link click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ5A8.png)

The error log has the following details:

*

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.sitecore_shell_controls_treeviewex_treeviewex_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\252d77a1\7452ed5e\App_Web_0so42fby.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Nested Exception
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Null ids are not allowed.
Parameter name: name
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.DataViewFactory.GetDataView(String name, String parameters)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeviewEx.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter output, Item parent)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeviewEx.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

*

Kindly help me if anyone knows the reason for this issue? I tried with one solution found in one of the site (by "disable" the authentication in the IIS) but it did not work for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon your question since we have the same problem, and [this article](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/05/sitecore-url-rewrites-and-the-failed-js-dialog/) describes exactly what we did and what problem we ran into.

I don't know if you added a URL rewrite rule for SEO to always use lowercase URLs, but it seems that Sitecore isn't a fan. So you should exclude this rule for your CM environment (what we did) or specifically exclude Sitecore urls (what they describe in the article).